# Knights of the Square Table

Tags: lateral-thinking, situation

*I am of the order of the valiant Knights of the Square Table, an elite fraternity—far more so than those so-called Knights of the Round Table. There are so many of them, but only two of us! I serve my lord the King. We are at war. His Majesty’s mortal enemy has come to us on a most unusual diplomatic mission, accompanied by his queen, and strangely, by a bishop of his vile kingdom. Their castle is nearby, but we are far from ours. I know this mission is only a pretense. All is lost for our great King!*

How does our brave knight know that all is lost?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because

> the square table is a chessboard

And

> the Knight's king is about to be checkmated by the overwelming forces (Queen, Bishop, Rook and King)

Comment: More importantly, (n Xvat naq Xavtug nybar pnaabg purpxzngr gur bccbfvat Xvat, rira vs gur bgure cvrprf pbhyq or pncgherq.)

Comment: @AxiomaticSystem the OP doesn't say rot13(gung gur Xvat naq Xavtug ner nybar.  Gurer'f zragvba bs gjb Xavtugf naq n Ebbx/Pnfgyr shegure njnl.  Gurer znl or zber.)

Comment: It does say "only two of us" though, weirdly. Since there is a mention of "our castle" as well later.

Comment: @justhalf true.  i interpreted that to mean two knights, since he was comparing to the many knights of the round table.

Comment: That makes sense too.